# How does a Jenkins pipeline step gets statement from groovy closures

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

So a docker pipeline step works like this

```
docker.image('maven:3.3.3-jdk-8').inside {
  sh "git clone .."
  sh 'mvn -B clean install'
}
```

where each statement of the closure is executed on the running container wrapped with `docker exec`

I wish to use the same technique, but on a container ran by `docker-compose`.

I want to create a step (unless there is one already out there).

Assume at an earliar stage I have a set of services running with `docker-compose`. I know the container ID of the container where I wish to run some jenkins steps. The step will look like this

```
withContainer(<id_of_the_container>) {
    sh "date"
    sh "cat mydog"
}
```

where each of the statement in the closure will be executed on the container, as if I am  effectively doing the following:

```
docker exec <id_of_the_container> sh "date"
docker exec <id_of_the_container> sh "cat mydog"
```

I can start defining a step like

```
def withContainer(containerId, Closure cl) {
   // I know I need to do something like
   // docker exec $containerId ...
}
```

how do I access the statements in the closure? Or am I going about it in the wrong way?

Answer (score -1):

I beleive this connected to your issue:

> Ability to run docker-exec etc. from a workflow
>
> https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26178

and the resolution: `Won't Do`

you can't get commands inside closure, but you could pass closure as a variable to some class. I can't validate this on pipeline and following code just to show approach

```groovy
//this funstion just for test purpose in a usual groovyconsole
//def sh(a){println "sh $a"}

class DockerHelper{
    Object delegate
    String containerId
    
    def withContainer(id, Closure cl){
        this.containerId=id
        this.with(cl)
        return this
    }
    
    def exec(command){
        delegate.sh(script: "docker exec -it $containerId /bin/bash -c '$command'")
    }
}

new DockerHelper(delegate:this).withContainer('my-running-mvn'){
    exec "date"
    exec "cat mydog"
}
```

Comment: the above answer doesn't executed the commands on a running container started by some other means (like `docker-compose`). The above starts a new container, with the image name passed as the `containerId` argument.

Comment: modified answer